# Как увидеть события, которые я добавляю в Firebase Crashlytics (Android) в консоли logcat?

Tags: android, firebase

Хочу, например, добавить нужный мне параметр в событие:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKey("str_key_id", "123")
```

Или отправить сообщение

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("hello")
```

Как мне проверить в logcat андроид студии то, что параметр передался? у меня нет доступа к crashlytics dashboard

Comment: разве что так как-то - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69339885/force-firebasecrashlytics-print-logs-to-console/69340289#69340289